# Java BitSet - wrapper to put chars/Strings in

Tags: java, casting, bit-manipulation

I'm making use of BitSet in Java to store values I have to serialize and deserialize into/from lower abstraction levels. This is to create a file-format container.

Currently I want to store a String into a BitSet:

```
private BitSet string_to_bit(String content_string) {

        BitSet result = new BitSet(this.size);

        char[] content_string_arr = new char[content_string.length()];
        for (char c : content_string_arr) {
            int tmp = (int) c;
            result += Integer.toBinaryString(tmp);
        }
}
```

The += is undefined on a BitSet, so the code is wrong at that point. Afaik I cannot override operators in Java 6. How would you elegantly wrap that operation? I don't want to end up repeating all these low level conversions over and over again because as it seems they repeat. Is there any .toBit equivalent? I can cast a BitSet to String with toString(). Why is there no de-abstraction?

Best,
Marius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know there is not `.toBit()` equivalent. you should write your own implementtation.

Here are 2 links may be helpful to you that [Converting Between a BitSet and a Byte Array](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Bits2Array.html)

and [Convert bitset to int array and string](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Convertbitsettointarrayandstring.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I find it quite odd that you are using a BitSet for serialization. It's not really designed for this. I'd suggest altering this approach first of all, as it will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

Have you considered using a [DataOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) instead? This is a much more standard approach and has the advantages that all the utility methods needed for writing Strings and other data types are already there for you to use....

Comment: I need a binary representation

Comment: @wishi: DataOutputStream writes binary representations. If you need them held in memory, wrap one round a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be that your code won't do what you want. For a start, your array will always be full of \0 (nul) characters.  Perhaps what you intended is much simpler.

I suspect there is no simple way to do what you want because BitSet isn't intended to store text.  Perhaps you intended

```
private static byte[] string_to_bytes(String text) {
    return text.getBytes();
}
```

Normally files contain bytes rather than bits.

Answer (score 1):

Is your data byte aligned? You could use a [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html).

As far as I know java does not provide functions or classes for bit level I/O.